# GNUradio: How to stream data in companion?

Tags: gnuradio

I'd like to set up GNUradio so I can remotely control a system and stream data to the control computer. So on one system there is a GNUradio program controlling a radio dongle of some kind, and on the other side there is a GNUradio with a WX gui and some control widgets. The computer with the controller sends some data to the radio computer, which receives some data from the dongle, then streams that back to the control computer, which displays that on a WX scope.

I've been told that the ZMQ blocks could do this kind of thing, but I was unable to receive any data this way, and the person who recommended it found the same problems, so I think that block might be broken at the moment. Is there any other way to do this using the standard GNUradio blocks?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. I'm sorry if that's against the rules, I had figured that since my other question received no answers and it's been several days, that it would be acceptable to ask again.

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, open

https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/master/gr-zeromq/examples

select one of the grc files by clicking on it, save it as "Raw" and then open it in gnuradio-companion.

All those examples should work correctly since the sockets are being opened on your local computer.

The example works on version on 3.7.10 of gnuradio.